# What does attributes_table do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Bit of a rails newbie ... this is really a two part question. The first part is: What is attributes_table in the following example:

```
  show :title => :name do
    attributes_table do
      row :id
      row :name
      row :username
      row :email
      row 'password reset?' do
        resource.reset_password_sent_at || 'no'
      end
      row :last_sign_in_at
      row :created_at
    end
  end
```

I tried out putting `attributes_table.inspect` which shows me a bunch of HTML but I'm assuming its an object with methods (and maybe a to_string method or something like that?).

My next question is: Why won't the show method do anything else with that attributes_table block in it? For example, if I add this line before `attributes_table do`:

```
render 'test'
```

It just seems to get ignored. If I remove the `attributes_table` block, then it shows the HTML. My eventual goal is to show some not-directly related data along with this record in active admin -- but I can't figure out how to show anything other then what activeadmin is built to let me show.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but I see some confusion I wanted to address.  The attributes_table is a method call.

Ruby has a bunch of DSLs which, because parentheses are optional in ruby, can look different than ruby code, but actually are.  With parentheses, the code would look like this:

```
show(:title => :name) do
  attributes_table() do
    row(:id)
    row(:name)
    row(:username)
    row(:email)
    row('password reset?') do
      resource.reset_password_sent_at() || 'no'
    end
    row(:last_sign_in_at)
    row(:created_at)
  end
end
```

Comment: that explains a little bit -- still trying to fumble my way through this :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What is attributes_table in the following example?

attributes_table is used to explicitly list the desired attribute\columns from the table for the show action

> 2) Why won't the show method do anything else with that
>   attributes_table block in it?
>
> The trick is to not try to use Arbre in the controller & render
>   something extra, as it gets all confused.

read https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/6-show-screens.md

then https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/725

also http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html

Comment: I've already found all those pages previously, and they aren't very helpful; either activeadmin has changed(?) or they are assuming knowledge that I don't have, or I'm simply an idiot. I'm just trying to show more info after the attributes table and failing at it pretty miserably for the past hour.

Comment: 1) create a view variable and assign it.  2) Modify the show page to use the variable.  If you need to render something else other than the show then add it in the view <%= render 'that' %>.  There are different ways.